# Background image all screen resolution ( my code cut photo)

Tags: html, css

The background image I want to adjust to all resolutions, but when writing **background-size: cover;** the whole photo is not visible and cut in half, why?

```
*, html{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('../img/image3.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Maybe because you're putting the bg image on every element. Put it on just the body tag to cover the whole viewport.

Comment: cover maintain aspect ratio

Comment: So don't put a photo in html? Put in div? @symlink

Comment: @koki put it on the `body` tag only. Give `html` and `body` a `height: 100%`

Comment: @symlink remove margin, padding and width?

Comment: @koki delete that entire style rule. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the entire style rule that you have. You probably want your html to have default margin, padding, and width properties, but you can deal with that when you're further along in the project. For now, give html and body a height of 100%. Then attach the background image to your body tag, so it will always take up 100% of the viewport. I added color and margin to your body tag as well, because color will be inherited by your html, and margin here is a "reset" style to make sure the browser doesn't put margins around the body tag:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/500/500);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
This is text directly inside the body tag.
<p>This is html inside the body tag, it should have its own styling</p>
```

Comment: But in this case the photo of the cat is cut in half.

Comment: I want it not to be cut and the whole photo to be

Comment: @koki see my edit. Perhaps you're looking for `background-position: center`

Comment: In your code, only the cat's face is visible. The original is also part of the below. I want the photo to be whole, not cropped